# Adding a UIViewController In SpriteBuilder COCOS2d 3.4

Tags: ios, swift, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I am trying to add a UIViewcontroller to a SpriteBuilder project so that I can display other UI items, but I am having trouble adding it to the main scene.

I create the view controller, but all I can find to add it is:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When I try this, Xcode tries to split the line up as it thinks it's 2 lines of code. I guess this is the Obj-C version? can anyone help with the Swift version?

Eventually I want to add a UIMediaPicker to this view controller. Is this the best way to go about it, or can I add the media picker directly to the COCO2D scene with the need for a view controller?

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cocos2d renders itself in its own view controller. For Swift, the syntax for accessing this view controller would be:

```
let view = CCDirector.sharedDirector().parentViewController!.view 
    // Returns a UIView of the cocos2d parent view controller.
```

You can then use the `view.addSubview(UIView view)` method to add subviews to the view controller.